# update sql table rows based on radio button values

Tags: php, jquery, sql

In a form I have ten paired radio button groups. The first button in each group has a value of Yes when checked, the second button has a value of No when checked.

A submit button in the form calls a jQuery function, serializes the values, and passes them to a PHP script.

How can I update ten consecutive SQL table row columns with the value of each radio button group using a for loop?

The code to update the table is below. I have verified that the radio buttons are serialized and their values passed to this PHP file. The code returns TRUE, but only the last row in the table is updated.

```
<?php
session_start();
require ("../config/root.php");
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Product 1 (5 Variants)
if(isset($_POST['product1'])) {
    $product1 = $_POST['product1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['product2'])) {
    $product2 = $_POST['product2'];
}
if(isset($_POST['product3'])) {
    $product3 = $_POST['product3'];
}
if(isset($_POST['product4'])) {
    $product4 = $_POST['product4'];
}
if(isset($_POST['product5'])) {
    $product5 = $_POST['product5'];
}
// Product 2 (5 Variants)
if(isset($_POST['product6'])) {
    $product6 = $_POST['product6'];
}
if(isset($_POST['product7'])) {
    $product7 = $_POST['product7'];
}
if(isset($_POST['product8'])) {
    $product8 = $_POST['product8'];
}
if(isset($_POST['product9'])) {
    $product9 = $_POST['product9'];
}
if(isset($_POST['product10'])) {
    $product10 = $_POST['product10'];
}
// Count the rows in the table
$count = "SELECT * FROM products";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$count)) {
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
for ($x = 1; $x <= $rowcount; $x++) {
$product=${'product'.$x};
$sql = "UPDATE products SET Availability = '$product' WHERE id = $x";
}
if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Update Success";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Include your code, it's better for us to understand you and bring help.

Comment: Just update all the columns: `UPDATE tablename SET col1 = :value1, col2 = :value2, col3 = :value3, ... WHERE ...`

Comment: No need for a loop.

Comment: "A submit button in the form calls a jQuery function, serializes the values, and passes them to a PHP script" - Any reason for this specific complexity? A regular form should work perfectly fine, too, unless you are also doing something else.

Comment: I've done hours of research on this subject, and it appears that I cannot loop through the radio button values and update the rows in the table.

@ Chriss Haas: If you could show me how to do this without the complexity I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by copying and pasting the if else statement into the for loop. So it didn't echo "Update Success" multiple times I commented out the success statement. If there's an error it will still echo the error to the main page.

So that it would still update the main page, I kept the if else statement after the for loop.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $rowcount; $x++) {
$product=${'product'.$x};
$sql = "UPDATE products SET Availability = '$product' WHERE id = $x";
if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
// echo "Update Success";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Update Success";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Each row of the SQL table updates now.

I researched this question for hours and found it had been asked several times in various forms without an answer that worked for me.

If this is method clunky or doesn't follow programming norms, I would be pleased to hear why.